# Переодоление барьера

Tags: javascript

Дан массив, элементы которого являются координатами барьеров на отрезке.
Мы можем делать прыжки равной длины с нуля направо.

Необходимо найти минимальную длину прыжка, которая позволит преодолеть все барьеры (в случае если таковую найти не удается, то преодолеваем одним прыжком).

Например в случае массива  `[5,3,6,7,9]`, минимальной длиной прыжка будет `4`.
Надо написать функцию, которая получает массив координат барьеров и возвращает минимальную длину прыжка.

```
function barrier(x) {
    x.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    let a = [];
    let k = 0;


    for (let i = 0; i < x[x.length - 1]; i++) {
        if (x[i - k] != (i + 1)) {
            a.push(i + 1);
            k++;
        }
    }
}

console.log(barrier([5,3,6,7,9]))   // Должен вывести 4
console.log(barrier([2,3]))   // Должен вывести 4
console.log(barrier([1,4,10,6,2]))   // Должен вывести 7
console.log(barrier([19,32,11,23]))   // Должен вывести 3
...
```

Пожолуйста помогите решить задачу...

Comment: Предлагаю следующий вариант: для каждого элемента массива барьеров, вычисляем все числа на которые "барьер" делится без остатка и добавляем их в массив; Ответом будет число от 1 до max(барьеров) отсутствующее в полученном массиве

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но нужно найти минимальную длину "прыжка"...

Comment: ну дак логика вашего решения вроде рабочая. ищите пропуски, проверяйте кратность. в чем помочь-то?

Comment: зачем вы таким образом редактируете свой вопрос? первый раз удалили описание собственно того, в чем у вас проблема была, а во второй удалили описание логики решения.

Comment: ваши пропуски можно найти, например, так `var result = Array(x.pop()-1).fill().map((v,i) => ++i).filter(v => !x.includes(v));`,

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Ваш код более оптималный и продвинутый чем мой. Просто не получается  написать алгоритм фильтрования чтобы в первом случае например из массива [1, 2, 4, 8] выбрать именно 4. Потому что [3,5,6,7,9] если начинать с нулья в случае 1 я после 3 шагов пересикаюсь с 3, в случае 2 после 3 шага я пересикаюсь с 6. Именно не получается из массива  [1, 2, 4, 8]  исключить 1 и 2...

Answer (score 0):

вы вроде вполне рабочую логику решения в вопросе описали.
Создайте массив пропусков, потом проходитесь по нему, и проверяйте, если ли в исходном числа кратные текущему. Как только не нашлось, то это и будет минимальный шаг.

```js
function barrier(x) {
    x.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    const max = x[x.length - 1];
    var result = Array(max).fill()
                     .map((v,i) => ++i)
                     .filter(v => !x.includes(v));    
                     
    let min = result.find(r => !x.some(v => v % r == 0));
    
    return min ? min : max + 1;
}

console.log(barrier([5,3,6,7,9]))   // Должен вывести 4
console.log(barrier([2,3]))         // Должен вывести 4
console.log(barrier([1,4,10,6,2]))  // Должен вывести 7
console.log(barrier([19,32,11,23])) // Должен вывести 3
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за то что нашли время и помогли. Вы мне многому научили...

Comment: @Mark тут спасибо выражают голосованием за ответ, или его принятием ;) поэтому [правила](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) советуют воздерживаться от комментариев вида "спасибо" 8)